# Jquery How to find all common options between two multi select instead of single

Tags: jquery

I am looking for an easy way of identifying the similar options between two selects.
I know we can use loops but similar to identifying a single option, is there a way to find bunch.

```
$("#select1 option").find(" #select2 option")
```

Comment: Please add more detail to your question and include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter()`

```
opt2_values = new Set($("#select2 option").map((i, el) => el.value).get());
$("#select1 option").filter((i, el) => opt2_values.has(el.value))
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing .This is creating problems in IE11 and I need to change this

Comment: IE11 has sets, but it doesn't have the form of the constructor that accepts an iterable argument. So create the set and then write your own loop to add the array elements to it. @user16880418